# Unencoding encoded URLs in a function

Tags: programming, import, string-manipulation

Is there a built-in function for decoding encoded URLs in *Mathematica*?
I would like to convert an encoded URL, for example
`https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fimages%2Fsrpr%2Flogo4w.png` 
into `https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo4w.png`
as attempting to directly access the encoded URL with `Import[]` fails.

Comment: StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3160924/618728

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Works nicely:

```
PercentDecode[s_String] := StringReplace[s, RegularExpression["%([[:xdigit:]]{2})"] :> 
                                         FromCharacterCode[FromDigits["$1", 16]]]

PercentEncode[s_String] := StringReplace[s, {" " -> "+", 
   RegularExpression["[^\\w/\\?=:._~]"] :> 
    StringJoin["%", ToUpperCase[IntegerString[First[ToCharacterCode["$0"]], 16]]]}]
```

Test:

```
PercentDecode["http://www.test.com/~a_b?i=Cos%5B2%5D"]
   "http://www.test.com/~a_b?i=Cos[2]"

PercentEncode["http://www.test.com/~a_b?i=Cos[2]"]
   "http://www.test.com/~a_b?i=Cos%5B2%5D"
```

Comment: Thanks for the function! Works nicely.

Comment: I'm not an expert for this, and the relevant standards have changed once in a while. But concerning `PercentEncode` maybe is worth noting that as far as I understand the decoding should always give unambiguous results while the encoding is somewhat arbitrary: it has not always been exactly specified which characters have to be encoded and which not, the latest RFCs about this seem to be more strict. So encoding with different functions/services might give different results, but I don't think that means there is an error as long as the decoding results in the same string.

Comment: @Albert: True, for the encoding I went with the characters that are frequently encoded by browsers. It should not be too hard to modify `PercentEncode[]`, of course.

Comment: @J.M.: to my understanding encoding is necessary for exactly those characters that are not "unreserved", everything else must be encoded if they are not to be interpreted with their "reserved" special meaning. So whether or not a character needs to be encoded depends on what they should be interpreted, if e.g. you want to send an url as an argument to a cgi script you would (unlike your `PercentEncode` does) need to encode "/". The uncertainty seems to be with all those characters that are not explicitly "reserved" or "unreserved"...

Answer (score 16):

There's also an internal function that does it:

```
ExternalService`DecodeString["https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fimages%2Fsrpr%2Flogo4w.png"]
```

At one time, the implementation of that function used J/Link code similar to Albert's code above, but now it is done in top-level Mathematica.

`` ExternalService`EncodeString `` does URL-encoding, if you want to go in the other direction.

Comment: Damn, so many undocumented functionality... :D

Answer (score 10):

There might be undocumented internal functions burried somewhere to do this, but it is relatively straightforward to get a result via JLink:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
LoadJavaClass["java.net.URLDecoder"];
url = "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fimages%2Fsrpr%2Flogo4w.png";
java`net`URLDecoder`decode[url]
```

see the Java documentation for more information about the `java.net` package and the `java.net.URLDecoder` class. The class `java.net.URLEncoder` might also be of interest...

With the information in e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) about "percent encoding" and the links to the relevant RFCs it is actually not difficult to build something based on `StringReplace` -- as J.M.'s answer shows in a very elegant way.

Answer (score 8):

`URLDecode` and `URLEncode` were introduced in Mathematica 10.0:

```
url = "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fimages%2Fsrpr%2Flogo4w.png";
URLDecode[url]
(*"https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo4w.png"*)
```

The symbol definition can be accessed as follows, which is scarily close to J. M.'s code above.

```
URLDecode[url];
Unprotect[URLDecode];
ClearAttributes[URLDecode, ReadProtected];
DownValues[URLDecode][[2]]

(*HoldPattern[
  URLDecode[URLUtilities`Encoding`PackagePrivate`s_String, 
   OptionsPattern[]]] :> 
 FromCharacterCode[
  List @@ StringReplace[
    URLUtilities`Encoding`PackagePrivate`s, {RegularExpression[
       "%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})"] :> FromDigits["$1", 16], 
     "+" :> First[ToCharacterCode[" "]], 
     URLUtilities`Encoding`PackagePrivate`char_ :> 
      First[ToCharacterCode[
        URLUtilities`Encoding`PackagePrivate`char]]}], 
  OptionValue[CharacterEncoding]]*)
```

Comment: Aww, I'm chuffed that I beat them to the implementation… :D The regex they picked is rather clunky-looking, tho.